# Clip an interpolated raster using points or create an extent polygon from points using ArcGIS for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, clip

I have a point feature class that I have imported from lat longs in an Excel spreadsheet. I have created a raster image from these points however areas outside of the point set extent are interpolated. I would either like to find a way to only interpolate within the points extent or clip the raster using the points / create an extent polygon from the points and use that to clip the raster.

[image]

Comment: Could you specify how did you do that?. I'm trying to clip a raster by a shp (poligon) and interpolate those lacking cells to have a raster that cover completely the poligon extension. Update: I need to do so in R.

Answer (score 1):

In order to clip raster by points:

1. Create a boundary polygon using "Toolboxes\System Toolboxes\Data Management Tools.tbx\Features\Minimum Bounding Geometry" tool
2. Using "Toolboxes\System Toolboxes\Data Management Tools.tbx\Raster\Raster Processing\Clip" tool with the created boundary

Alternatively, try using Convex Hull option in the first tool (Minimum Bounding Geometry).

Comment: Hi, thanks but unfortunately step 1 doesn't give the desiered outcome. I have however discovered a work around by converting the points to raster and adjusting the cell size. Then, using a custom tool to create a polygon of the raster extent, then use the clip tool.

Comment: Have you tried using Convex Hull option in the first tool (Minimum Bounding Geometry)?

Or there is another problem with that?

Comment: It doesn't give the desired results unfortunately but the work around method did the job.